# Is this code thread safe with ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

```
public class Test {

    private static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.processData("data/test.txt");
    }

    public void processData(String filePath){
        File folder = new File(filePath);
        for (String filename : folder.list()) {
        String filePath = folder.toPath().resolve(filename).toString();
        File inputfile = new File(filePath);

        if (inputfile.isDirectory()) {
            processData(filePath);
        }else{
        pool.execute(() -> {
            log.info("Start processing " + filePath);
            Processor.process(filePath);
        });
    }
  }
}

class Processor{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Processor.class);

    public static void process(String filePath){

        try{

           List<Document> documets = DocumentProcessor.analyze(filePath);
           ...

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class DocumentProcessor{

    private static Tokenizer tokenizer = null;
    private static Resource resource = null;
    private static Checker checker = null;
    private static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    static {
       // static initialization here
       // ommited
    }

   public static List<Document> analyze(String filePath){
       BufferedReader br = null;

        List<Document> processedDocs = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath)));
            String line = null;
            List<Future<Document>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                Callable<Document> callable = new FileThread(line, filePath);
                tasks.add(pool.submit(callable));
            }
            for (Future<Document> task : tasks) {
                try {
                    processedDocs.add(task.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error("InterruptedException Failure: " + line);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    log.error("Thread ExecutionException e: " + line);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return processedDocs;
  } 
}



public class FileThread implements Callable<Document> {

    private String textLine;
    private String filePath;

    public TextThread(String textLine, String filePath) {
        this.textLine = textLine;
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public Document call() {

        ParsedDoc parsedDoc = JSONDocParser.parse(textLine, Source.news);
        Document doc = new Document(parsedDoc.getURL(), parsedDoc.getDocTime());
 doc.setDocument(Parser.parseDoc(parsedDoc.getText());

        return doc;
    }
}
```

From this code, multi-threading is used in processData() method with an ExecutorService class. My question is:
1) Do I need any type of thread synchronization in either Processor or DocumentProcessor class? The class 'Processor' doesn't have any instance or class variable except the log variable.

2) If this is part of a big project and the only multi-threading code is in the Test class, as shown here. Do I need to worry about threading issue in all other classes, assuming there is no threading protection in all other classes.

The reason I am asking this is that, based on the examples I saw, it seems if ExecutorService is used in this idiom, I don't need to worry about threading issues in all other classes, i.e. Processor or DocumentProcessor. Is that true?

EDIT:
Please see my edited code. I think now it can illustrate my question better. Thanks.

Comment: What does `DocumentProcessor.analyze(filePath)` do? Does it hold state?

Comment: Thread safety is an issue that comes along when dealing with _more than one thread_ that execute the same code. Your code doesn't have this.

Comment: But if several threads (regardless whether from a pooled service or created manually by you) run the same code, you always have to look for thread safety.

Comment: Without seeing the code of DocumentProcessor it's not possible to answer this.  If DocumentProcessor has static instance variables that are modified by the analyze() method then you will potentially have problems with thread safety.

Comment: Yes, DocumentProcessor has a number of static variables defined.

Comment: @Speakjava, if I add a "syncronized" keyword to "process", would that make it safe?

Comment: No Threads.... I assume single thread sort of means its thread safe :P

Comment: if any of the other classes is used, directly or indirectly, by Processor or DocumentProcessor, this classes are also subject to multi-threading

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger So I need to care about thread safety of each and every class in a project, since all classes are related to each other directly or indirectly?

Comment: @user697911 You only need to care about thread safetey **if and only if** multiple threads will run your code. Your code example above shows only _one_ thread running the processing, so you do not need to think about thread safety. Clear now?

Comment: short answer: yes, and note: `pool.execute` is starting only (at most) one Thread, so the above code is not the best example for multi-threading...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger and Seelenviruose, but Speakjava's comments above are saying that it depends on my analyze() implementation, so there is a potential thread safety issue in this code.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, it's creating a thread pool. Why there is only one thread running the processing in my code?

Comment: "short answer: yes" != "long answer: depends, and not sure if we can/should discuss that here" // the pool has threads, but you are calling execute only one time. The Executor is not able to figure out how to divide YOUR code (or better, Runnable) over multiple Threads...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Thread safety is an issue when more than one thread will *access the same data*. Whether they execute the same code is irrelevant. Granted, in this example there is also no concurrent data access, so thread safety indeed not an issue. But it’s important not to tell wrong criteria.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger. My code is expanded. Please take another look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronized required only if a critical section access by multiple thread.In your case what it seems you are calling as service and there is no shared code between any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is protect **critical sections** of your code using synchronization.  This means that *only* where you have state that could potentially be modified by more than one thread simultaneously.  If you don't have access to the DocumentProcessor code then you could synchronize around the call to analyze(), but that would probably be too coarse.  If most of your work is in that method then you will lose much of the benefit of using multiple threads.

Ideally the analyze() method should be made thread safe so you would synchronize only where the method modifies static instance variables of DocumentProcessor.

Comment: "static instance variables", did you mean "static class variables"?

Comment: I added the DocumentProcessor and analyze(). Do I need to do any protection? There is another ExecutorService in the processor.

Comment: I feel the only place I need to protect is the "textLine" variable in the call() method of the FileThread class. Is that true?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, static class variables.  Since the code you show for the analyze() method does not modify any of the static class values you do not need to add any synchronisation to be thread safe. I'm not sure if there's a typo, as you have a static ExecutorService called pool and then reference m_pool in the method, which does not appear to come from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the typo. What about the FileThread class? Do I need to protect the field "textLine"? Is it accessed by multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: No, in this case testLine is an instance variable and so each thread will have its own copy.  It does not need to be protected from other threads since they have no way to access it directly.